# Why do all the async image loading (SDWebImage, AFNetworking) libraries use UIImageView instead of UIImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, afnetworking, sdwebimage

Am I missing something? Wouldn't allow it to be used with UIImage be more versatile than just UIImageView? You could hand the UIImage around and use it for different things, where a UIImageView can really only be added to the view.

My initial thought was what if you hand it to another class and the UIImage hasn't loaded yet, it would receive `nil` and not be passed anything new. But the same applies if you pass a UIImageView, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 4):

#### AFNetworking

You're right, the AFNetworking category implementation (UIImageView+AFNetworking) is bare-bones.

But you're missing [AFImageResponseSerializer](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.1.0/Classes/AFImageResponseSerializer.html), which validates and decodes images and provides a few options for handling them.  (In the old 1.x version of AFNetworking, this functionality is in [AFImageRequestOperation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.3.3/Classes/AFImageRequestOperation.html).)

#### SDWebImage

Similarly, you're only looking at the very basic implementation of SDWebImage.  There are a LOT of options here, so I suggest you review some of the other classes, but at the most basic level, you can get a UIImage like this:

```
SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
[manager downloadWithURL:imageURL
                 options:kNilOptions
                 progress:^(NSUInteger receivedSize, NSUInteger expectedSize)
                 {
                     // update a progress view
                 }
                 completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished)
                 {
                     if (image)
                     {
                         // Do something with the image; cacheType tells you if it was cached or not.
                     }
                 }];
```

#### Asynchronous loading

> What if you hand it to another class and the UIImage hasn't loaded yet?

Well, it's all loaded asynchronously, so the completion block wouldn't get called until the UIImage *was* loaded.