# AFNetworking and Collection View Blocking Main Thread

Tags: uiimageview, uicollectionview, afnetworking, grand-central-dispatch, realm

Having a little trouble working with AFNetworking and a collection view. I'm using AFNetworking to make a call to Foursquare's photos API. I construct the photo URL given to me from Foursquare and store that URL in realm.io. I then call the foursquare URLs from realm and use those URLs on AFNetworking's setImageWithURL method in my collection view's `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. When the view controller that thing is done in initially loads it seems to momentarily block the main thread (for about 1 second) until the images start showing on my collection view. I'm not sure why and was wondering if anyone has a suggestion for better performance? Thanks in advance!

Here is my code below for `cellForItemAtIndexPath`:

```
 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *identifier = @"photoCell";

UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
UIImageView *wineryImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

_photo = [_wineryPhotosArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[wineryImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_photo.photoURLString] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Grapes"]];

return cell;
}
```

`_wineryPhotosArray` is my realm array containing the photo URLs from Foursquare. Also, I tried wrapping the `setImageWithURL` method in `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_que)` but this didn't seem to do much.

This is my code for my Foursquare Photo API call that then stores the URLs in realm:

```
 -(void)getFoursquarePhotos {

FoursquarePhotosAPI *foursquarePhotoAPI = [FoursquarePhotosAPI initWithClientSecret:_clientSecret clientID:_clientId venueId:_venueId];

[foursquarePhotoAPI foursquarePhotosAPI:^(NSDictionary *data) {

    for (NSDictionary *foursquarePhotos in data) {

        _photo = [Photo initWithPrefix:[foursquarePhotos valueForKey:@"prefix"] size:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@x%@", [foursquarePhotos valueForKey:@"height"], [foursquarePhotos valueForKey:@"width"]] suffix:[foursquarePhotos valueForKey:@"suffix"]wineryId:_venueId];

        RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
        [realm beginWriteTransaction];
        [realm addOrUpdateObject:_photo];
        [realm commitWriteTransaction];
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    }
  }];  
}
```

Comment: You can use a stackshot to see what's happening while it appears frozen, and the time profiler (in Instruments) to figure out why it's taking so long.

Comment: You also might try moving `beginWriteTransaction`, `commitWriteTransaction`, and `reloadData` outside the `for` loop, so you aren't committing many transaction, and you only reload the data once, when it's done. You could also try performing the realm operations on a background thread and then reloading the collection view on the main thread when it's done.

Comment: Thanks moving the realm writes and reload data outside of the for loop seemed to help. I think that's what was slowing it down momentarily.

Answer (score 0):

Aaron is definitely right that pulling `beginWriteTransaction` and `commitWriteTransaction` out of the for loop should improve performance. Realm's general rule-of-thumb is to try and batch as many write operations within one write transaction as possible.

Beyond that, I get the feeling the reason for your unacceptable scroll performance is that the image data you're downloading is getting decoded on the main thread after you've added them to their respective image views.

Images aren't decoded at the time of calling `[UIImageView setImage:]` but are lazily-loaded by Core Animation at the time that the view is about to be rendered by the GPU (So encapsulating that code in a `dispatch_async` won't do anything).

According to [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21844098/why-do-all-the-async-image-loading-sdwebimage-afnetworking-libraries-use-uiim), AFNetworking's `UIImage` download category is quite bare-bones, and doesn't perform this background image decoding itself, but it proposes several solutions that will, such as `AFImageRequestOperation`, or `SDWebImage`.

For more information on the image decoding/rendering pipeline of iOS, I'd recommend you watch the WWDC 2014 video: Advanced Graphics and Animations for iOS Apps. :)

Comment: Thanks for the additional info @TiM. I will watch the WWDC video. Still a little new to all of this but hoping this will provide me with a deeper understanding.